# Product Config option works like Amazon

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, color-swatches, configurable-swatches

I have enabled the display out of stock products from the admin configuration. Now those config option are displaying on the front-end and it works fine also. If any product is out of stock then that option is disabled and we can not click/select that option.

Now my client wants the functionality similar to Amazon. Check  this attached screenshot.
So you can click even the crossed out options and other options auto select the next available. so in this case, if you select the crossed out green, then the apparel size and kit / bare options select the next available.

In the Amaon, out of stock option are clickable and based on that other options get updated.
Check this product link for more info: [https://www.amazon.com/Under-Armour-Sportstyle-T-Shirt-Medium/dp/B077XQLK9N](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B077XQLK9N)

[image]